# App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, info.plist

App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

I have all the solutions possible like:    `    NSAppTransportSecurity

```
<dict>

    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>

    <true/>

</dict>`
```

and

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

But still facing the same error.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32894812/760275

Answer (score 5):

The first settings is not correct, this should be:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

The second settings only works if you are on `https` but the server does not support TLSv1.2

Comment: thank you for the reply.
I tried your solution but I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: it worked for me, it needs to be on Information Property List node -> App Transport Security Settings -> Allow Arbitrary Loads (Boolean) -> Yes